# Scrape the data from website and store it in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the xml or html web extracted data from a websource using python and it is in the table format,I wish to put only the ** ** marked data in an array as [][] how to do the same? Single array storing the same one by one as well fine.

My idea is to get the symbol BHEL and its value 80.50 as an individual element so that i can use this for my coding.

```
<table width="100%"><tr><td>
<div class="tphead"><h2>Option Chain (Equity Derivatives)</h2></div>
</td><td align="right">
<div style="float:right; font-size:1.2em;">
<span>**Underlying Stock:** <b style="font-size:1.2em;">**BHEL** **80.50**</b> </span>
<span>**As on May 11, 2018 15:30:30 IST**<a> <img onclick="refresh();" src="/live_market/resources/images/refressbtn.gif" style="cursor: pointer" title="refresh"/></a></span></div>
</td></tr></table>
```

I want to filter only these data and store it an array one by one .

and the array shall be as below. Any python code support can be provided here.

```
Option Chain (Equity Derivatives)
Underlying Stock: BHEL 80.50
As on
May 11, 2018
15:30:30 IST
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you need but looks like you want to get the text within HTML tags using BeautifulSoup4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

extracted_text = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_string, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all(recursive=False):
    text = tag.text.strip()
    if text:
        extracted_text.append(text)
```

*your_string* is the html code you fetched

*recursive=False* is used to go only one level down on nested HTML tags, otherwise it would extract same text twice (or more)

Comment: No this wont work;I have lot other text data as resulted output which i do not want to put it in array .Only the above given extract has to be put an array